# Line appears in final render

Tags: rendering

In the LookDev mode, everything looks perfectly fine.
[image]
However, when I render the image or go into rendered view, there is a strange line between to vertices.
[image]
There is no crease and it is a flat face.
[image]

Comment: It seems these lines are a shadow from one light source. In look dev, there is a environment texture that enlightens the scene. But this light source is not used when rendering. Try to use several light sources or add an environment texture.

Comment: I suspect your faces are not actually *planar* - try viewing your face "side-on" as a visual check that all vertices are actually in the same plane. If not, adjust them so they are (one way to do this is to select the face in Edit mode, set your Transform Orientation to 'Normal' and press S, Z, 0, Enter to scale all vertices back to a plane (although this will distort your mesh).

Comment: This worked perfectly, maybe answer it instead of comment it so i can check solved